# Why does my camera make a whirring noise during a long exposure?

Tags: long-exposure, sony, shutter

I have a [Sony Alpha a55](http://store.sony.com/p/SLT-A55VL/en/p/SLTA55VL).

[image]

When I take a long exposure photo, while the shutter is open, the camera makes a whirring sound. **What causes this noise and why is it necessary to the camera's operation?** (I have interface sounds turned off — so I suppose this is some piece of the hardware physically making a noise.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm familiar with Canon lenses featuring Image Stabilization that can emit a faint "whir" as IS operates.  Your Sony body has a form of image stabilization built into the body, and if that's on during a long exposure, you might be hearing that as it operates.

If you're shooting long-exposure shots with the camera mounted on a tripod (which would be best), it's usually recommended that image stabilization be turned off (I believe this to be the case for your a55).

Comment: Can you expand on your last point? What's the benefit in turning off image stabilization?

Comment: I've heard it described as the stabilization getting itself into a form of feedback loop with itself.  As far as I know, this problem can vary from one implementation to the next, so in some cases, it's not really a problem at all.  Any time you're using a good tripod, though, you shouldn't need any stabilization, so there's little harm in turning it off.

Comment: We have a winner! I tried disabling SteadyShot and the noise went away. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it!